# Remove Currency Symbol PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with a jQuery slider allowing a price range to be selected.

The JavaScript that runs the slider also adds a prefix of the `£` symbol to each price.

I am trying to remove the `£` symbol before the form is submitted, as the price values in the database are only `numeric` without any currency symbol.

I am trying the `str_replace` function but the code below is not working?

```
<div id="slider">
    <input type="text" id="price-min" name="price-min" <?php 
        $price-min = str_replace('£', '', $price-min);
    ?>>
    </input>
    <input type="text" id="price-max" name="price-max" <?php 
        $price-max = str_replace('£', '', $price-max);
    ?>>
    </input>
</div>
```

Comment: try to give the char value

Comment: PHP variables can't have dashes in their names...

Answer (score 23):

You can just filter the variable.

```
<?php
$value = "£200";
echo filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

[Live Preview](https://eval.in/186972)

### Edit

> I'll need to cover all values from £0 - £1,000 and also strip out the comma from the £1,000 figure - Is this possible?

```
<?php
$value = "£200";
echo filter_var( str_replace(",", "", $value), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

[Live Preview](https://eval.in/187001)

Or even sanitize as a float

```
<?php
$value = "£1,200";
echo filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
```

[Live Preview](https://eval.in/187011)

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores

Your variables have `-` in them, making them invalid.

### Edit 2

Removing the `£` with javascript, use a regular expression.

```
var s = "£1,300";
s.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

[Live Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/puzez8vq/)

### Edit 3

If you're accepting negative decimal numbers (ie: -£20,000.06/-£20000.06), then use the `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` flag. This issue was pointed out by [Milan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824033/milan) as the current answers didn't handle this test-case.

```
<?php
$value = "-£20,000.06";
echo filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

[Live Preview](https://eval.in/652936)

Comment: I'll need to cover all values from £0 - £1,000 and also strip out the comma from the £1,000 figure - Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks, would I need to add this code separately for each value, i.e £200, £300, £400 or can it be incorporated into one piece of code?

Comment: Where `$value` is, replace with your two variables - or make it a function call. Max calls is twice. (min and max price)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have tried using the edited code above but it still doesn't return any results when passed through the form?

Comment: Use the filter_var solution just before you're inserting into the database.

Comment: Sorry confused now, I'm a novice when it comes to PHP. How would I go about removing the values with Javascript? The values are assigned to the input fields by the JS code and change as the slider is moved

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think I may need to go down the route of showing the currency symbol outside of the input field as it seems to be causing other problems

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can remove the pound sign after the form is submitted because php is a server side language. So either you remove it from the javascript slider so it won't be added to the value attribute or you use the function from hd.'s answer in the php script that the form points to.

Comment: Just because PHP is a server side language does not mean it cannot handle the `£` character.

Comment: "I am trying to remove the £ symbol before the form is submitted".. Did you even read his post? Look how he wrote the php code and how he's using functions on undeclared vars. He can handle it before the form submit with php via AJAX.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I misread your answer. +1 for pointing out you can remove it with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all characters, but numbers, dots and minus signs you should use:

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9-.]+/', '', $string);
```

Once applied this function will return a numeric value, which can be correctly converted to float value. It will also keep the negative numbers intact, which is quite important. The other solutions presented here, convert them to positive numbers, which is incorrect and dangerous, if dealing with monetary values.

Comment: *"The other solutions presented here, convert them to positive numbers, which is incorrect and dangerous"* Actually, they don't: https://eval.in/634165

Comment: As I said there are issues with the currently accepted answer as it will not recognize strings correctly as monetary values and is dangerous to use. Look at the example string: "-£20,000.06" - Preview here https://eval.in/652877

Comment: Good catch! I've modified my answer for a solution using `filter_var`. - https://eval.in/652936

Answer (score 1):

Currency symbols in HTML are HTML entities(I mean, frontend value) so using signs of currency directly to find and replace them is not possible, so using as below to get only digit in PHP.

```
$price = '$109.99';
$digitOnly = preg_replace('/&.*?;/', '', $price);
```